# AddToCart not displaying in basket

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a food shop using MVC where users can add menu items to a basket. However I am having a problem with the 'add to cart' feature.

This is a class I made to get the items from the database

```
public class Item
{
    private RestaurantA pr = new RestaurantA();
    private int quantity;

    public Item()
    { }

    public Item(RestaurantA product, int quantity)
    {
        this.pr = product;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int Quantity { get => quantity; set => quantity = value; }
    public RestaurantA Pr { get => pr; set => pr = value; }
}
```

This is the method for the 'add to cart' in order controller

```
public ActionResult OrderNow()
    {
        if (Session["cart"] == null)
        {
            List<Item> cart = new List<Item>();
            cart.Add(new Item(db.RestaurantA.Find(id), 1));
            Session["cart"] = cart;
        }
        else
        {
            List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
            cart.Add(new Item(db.RestaurantA.Find(id), 1));
            Session["cart"] = cart;                
        }
        return View("Cart");
    }
```

Also, I get a small wriggly line underneath both '(id)' with the error "The name 'id' does not exist in the current context". I dont know why this error is there because 'id' is in the model and the problem doesnt exist in other classes.

```
public class RestaurantA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Item Type")]
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

The cart view has a table that lists the name and price.

```
<table class=" table table-bordered table-hover">
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
@foreach (Item item in (List<Item>)Session["cart"])
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Pr.ID</td>
        <td>@item.Pr.Name</td>
        <td>@item.Pr.Price</td>
        <td>@item.Quantity</td>
        <td>@(item.Pr.Price * item.Quantity)</td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Each menu item has a link to add to cart next to it

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { <td class=" btn btn-default">
                   @Html.ActionLink("Add to Cart", "OrderNow", "Order", new { id = item.ID}, null)     
                </td>  }
```

The problem I am having is that when I click on 'Add to Cart', it does not do it and the cart stays empty. I am not sure why this is and I appreciate it if anyone can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: No where in your `OrderNow()` method have your declared a variable named `id`. But since you passing a variable named `id` to that method in your 'Add to Cart' links, that method needs a parameter named `id` - `public ActionResult OrderNow(int id)`

Comment: Thanks Stephen - It works now however there is another issue. Everytime I refresh the page, it adds another item automatically. Any way to get behind this?

Comment: Your changing data, so it must be a POST, not a GET!

Comment: Could you explain a little please? Where should be post? Sorry im still new to MVC and learning. Thank you

Comment: You have a form(s) in your view, and you submit that form to a `[HttpPost]` method that adds the item to your cart.

Comment: I suppose you mean making my method (OrderNow) a [HttpPost], however this does not work. If I try to add an item to cart while the [HttpPost] is there, it ends up giving an error.

Comment: So your expecting me to guess what mistakes you made?

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("OrderNow", "Order", new { id = item.ID }, FormMethod.Post))

Comment: Not at all, maybe I have not been clear enough. I will leave it for now. Thank you very much for all your help!